# Plotting multiple columns in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to plot all columns of a data frame based on a column in the data frame. The df basically looks like this:

```
   iters  a     b     c
1    1    0.92  0.83  0.97
2    2    0.12  0.93  0.76
3    3    0.55  0.41  0.87
4    4    0.43  0.55  0.49
```

So far I have tried this code:

```
 df <- melt(acc_s1,  id.vars = 'iter', variable.name = 'letter')
 ggplot(df, aes(iter,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = letter))
```

Unfortunately, my results looks like this (don't mind the slightly different names):
[image]

Any ideas, where this comes from?
Thanks

Comment: First, you have a typo in your code - in original data set there is a variable `iters` and in melted one it calls `iter`. Check what is `df`, whether does it have desired format.

Comment: `value` looks like a character in this plot, did you try `as.numeric(value)` in your `ggplot` call ?

Comment: thanks @bVa as.numeric() did the job!